# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null reference

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class, methods, typeerror

I am creating a platformer game. However, I have encountered an error after creating a collision boundary on platform to make the player jump on the platform without dropping.

I have create a rectangle box and I export it as `platForm`

Here's the output of the error:
The error keep repeating itself over and over again....

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Boy/BoyMove()
```

Main class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.*;

public class experimentingMain extends MovieClip 
{
    var count:Number = 0;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10,count);

    var classBoy:Boy;



    //var activateGravity:gravity = new gravity();

    var leftKey, rightKey, spaceKey, stopAnimation:Boolean;

    public function experimentingMain() 
    {
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, scoreUp);
        myTimer.start();



        classBoy = new Boy();
        addChild(classBoy);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressTheDamnKey);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, liftTheDamnKey);
    }

    public function pressTheDamnKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 37)
        {
            leftKey = true;
            stopAnimation = false;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39)
        {
            rightKey = true;
            stopAnimation = false;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            spaceKey = true;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }
    }

    public function liftTheDamnKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 37)
        {
            leftKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39)
        {
            rightKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            spaceKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }
    }

    public function scoreUp(event:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        scoreSystem.text = String("Score : "+myTimer.currentCount);
    }

}
   }
```

Boy class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Boy extends MovieClip
{
    var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    //the main character's speed
    var mainSpeed:Number = 15;
    //whether or not the main guy is jumping
    //var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
    var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
    //how quickly should the jump start off
    var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 40;
    //the current speed of the jump;
    var jumpSpeed:Number = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 10;

    var theGround:ground = new ground();


    //var theCharacter:MovieClip;

    public var currentX,currentY:int;

    public function Boy()
    {
        this.x = 600;
        this.y = 540;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, BoyMove);
    }

    public function BoyMove(event:Event):void
    {
        currentX = this.x;
        currentY = this.y;

        if (MovieClip(parent).leftKey)
        {
            currentX -=  mainSpeed;
            MovieClip(this).scaleX = 1;
        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).rightKey)
        {
            currentX +=  mainSpeed;
            MovieClip(this).scaleX = -1;
        }


        if (MovieClip(parent).spaceKey || mainJumping)
        {
            mainJump();
        }

        this.x = currentX;
        this.y = currentY;
    }

    public function mainJump():void
    {
        currentY = this.y;


        if (! mainJumping)
        {

            mainJumping = true;
            jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit * -1;
            currentY +=  jumpSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            if (jumpSpeed < 0)
            {
                jumpSpeed *=  1 - jumpSpeedLimit / 250;
                if (jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/12)
                {
                    jumpSpeed *=  -2;
                }
            }
        }
        if (jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit)
        {
            jumpSpeed *=  1 + jumpSpeedLimit / 120;
        }
        currentY +=  jumpSpeed;

        if (MovieClip(this).y > 500)
        {
            mainJumping = false;
            MovieClip(this).y = 500;
        }



        this.y = currentY;
    }
}
    }
```

Platformer class: This is the class I want to set the boundary for the rectangle (platForm)

```
package 
{
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class platForm extends MovieClip
{
    var level:Array = new Array();
    var classBoys:Boy = new Boy();
    var speedx:int = MovieClip(classBoys).currentX;

    public function platForm() 
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
        {
            if (getChildAt(i) is platForm) 
            {
                level.push(getChildAt(i).getRect(this));
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < level.length; i++) 
        {
            if (MovieClip(classBoys).getRect(this).intersects(level[i]))
            {
                if (speedx > 0) 
                {
                    MovieClip(classBoys).x = level[i].left - MovieClip(classBoys).width/2;
                }
                if (speedx < 0) 
                {
                    MovieClip(classBoys).x = level[i].right - MovieClip(classBoys).width/2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to see exactly what is happening without being able to run your code, but the error is saying that something within your BoyMove() method is trying to reference a property (or method) of something that is null.  Having looked at the BoyMove() method, I can see that there isn't a lot there that could cause this problem.  The other two candidates would be

```
MovieClip(parent)
```

or

```
MovieClip(this)
```

You are attempting to access properties of both of those MovieClips.  One of them must not be initialized as you expect.  I suggest you do some basic debugging on that method by commenting out the lines with MovieClip(parent) and see if you still get the error.  Then try the same with the line with MovieClip(this).  That should be able enough to isolate the issue.

Comment: The culprit is MoveClip(parent). However, without the MovieClip(parent), the controls of my character wouldn't work.

Comment: Using MovieClip(parent) means that you are performing a type-cast of 'parent' into the type MovieClip, right? I believe that if the cast fails, for some reason, it will return null. What is the parent of the class Boy?

Comment: Actually the casting with `MovieClip(parent)` will not return null if the cast fails - that will throw a different exception. Casting with `as` returns null: `parent as MovieClip`. So perhaps `parent` is just null.

Comment: @SunilD. This is what I was thinking. Minelava, what is the parent of Boy? (This really sounds like a poorly constructed sentence, doesn' it?)

Comment: Try to make sure BoyMove() doesn't get called before it's added to the stage. You can use an "addedToStage" event to wait. That 10ms timer in your main class seems suspicious too.

Comment: The above answer should do it from Sunil D.  The stage referenced from the Boy class is null because the stage is being called (from BoyMove function) before the boy has even probably been added to the stage and thus the null identifier on the parent (the stage).

Add an event listener in your main class as mentioned above and in the handler function add the line:
'addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, BoyMove);'

So the listener is only created from the addedToStage event.

Comment: @Nathan I think it must be from experimentingMain class

Comment: @Minelava From what I can tell, it sounds like BoyMove() must be getting called before you add classBoy as a child of experimentingMain. But the only thing I can see that you are doing is creating a timer that calls scoreUp(), which doesn't appear to call BoyMove().

Comment: @Placeable. I tried but still error 1120: Access of undefined property BoyMove